# Beamer + PGF produces "invalid" PDF / crashes acroread

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, acrobat

I've got a complex presentation in pdflatex/beamer using lots of TikZ graphics and included images. It works perfectly under linux/evince but not in acroread: some of the graphics do not display and during a presentation, a dialog box pops up with "An error exists on this page ..."

I'm still trying to isolate a minimal instance that causes this problem but has anyone had anything similar and/or any pointers to how I could debug this?

Versions involved (from logfile):

- pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
- LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
- Document Class: beamer 2007/03/11 cvs version 3.07
- pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
- acroread 9 for linux (but does the same on Windows)

EDIT: minimal example (minus image files)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{} % Not sure what this does myself.
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclaremask{mask}{mask.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=24pt,interpolate=true,mask=mask]{tick}{tick.png}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=circle,minimum size=2cm,color=gray,draw,fill] at (0, 0) {};
  \node at (0, 0) {\pgfuseimage{tick}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT2:

- example.pdf: http://www.2shared.com/document/ZK_Crjou/example.html
- example.tex: http://www.2shared.com/file/HO9xY4Cm/example.html
- mask.png: http://www.2shared.com/photo/x6M0ghuX/mask.html
- tick.png: http://www.2shared.com/photo/Eg51PBe6/tick.html

Comment: Are you using `hyperref` and `patterns` library too?

Comment: Notice that there is a newer version of `beamer`. I do not know about the others.

Comment: If you can put your pdf online, others can let you know if they have the same problems. The same is true if you provide us with a complete minimal working example that doesn't work for you, so others can compile it.

Comment: Ok so the problem seems to occur when I use pgf's image masking to get an image display above a pgf filled shape. Here's a minimal example (I edited the main post).

Comment: I don't know if its any helpful, but running the command `convert -density 96 example.pdf -density 96 example2.pdf` produced an error `**** Warning: File encountered 'rangecheck' error while processing an image.` with some future comments such as "produced by pdfTeX-1.40.10" or a comment that says the file got repaired. However, `example2.pdf` contains only grey disc and beamer navigation buttons.

Comment: You don't even need the grey shape. Just the masked image is causing issues with Acroread (and convert).

Comment: I tried converting the mask to various formats and could not succeed.

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't convert mask.png to another format or you couldn't get the PDF to display in acroread?

Answer (score 1):

If you are under Unix-based systems, you can configure your **CUPS** (Common Unix Printing System) to print directly to `.pdf`, you get some hints using google on "cups pdf", I won't put links here because the hints are system-dependent.

Then you can print your `.pdf` from **evince** to another `.pdf`. The resulting file is readable by **Acrobat**, just you lose all `hyperref` functions as well as clickable beamer navigation and similar stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that is in fact what I did last time I had this problem - though I'm still hoping for a solution that doesn't break all the other neat features that beamer can stick in a PDF.

Comment: I understand, I just thought that despite its stupidity, it might solve the problem for somebody, maybe in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I see something like this happen very often (depending on the actual mask). Acrobat displays garbage as mask (a very slanted version of the mask) And seems to be a problem with Acrobat reading the internal PNG image (`acroread 9.4.1`), Evince shows it correctly.

The workaround I found is to have the mask in other format like JPG. (Usually, masks in JPG format are larger size than PNG)