# Transparent png prints incorrectly from Reader

Tags: graphics, transparency, png, adobe

I have a transparent PNG over a tikzpicture. This prints fine from TeXworks (left image), but from Adobe Reader the transparent area is noticeable (right image). Since most people use Reader, this is a problem.

Without matching the colours how do I prevent this?

The code for the images is as follows:

```
% document class
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

% stuff
\pagestyle{empty}         % no page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}     % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                   % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % figures
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Call colours by their svgnames
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} } %images are kept here


% Create column layout
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.24\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
  \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
  \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.22\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{2\columnsep}

% right frame
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

% define custom colours
\definecolor{PaleGrey}{RGB}{99,99,99}

\begin{document}

%Dagger
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill [fill=PaleGrey!10] (0,0.8cm) -- (0,-23cm) -- (5cm,-26.5cm) -- (5cm,0.8cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\hspace*{\parindent}% text in specimen is set into page somewhat
\begin{minipage}[c]{5.1cm}% adjust to taste
\begin{center}

%Picture
\includegraphics{logo}

% Three Blind Mice

% end justify center
\end{center}\normalsize
\framebreak
\end{minipage}
% End of mini page

\end{document}
```

And the [image itself is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhmlI.png)

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to generate the picture?

Comment: Might also be an idea to provide the png to be downloaded from somewhere (thee are loads of services for this).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. AR is known to have problems with images that are transparent. I'll search the archives to see if there is a solution.

Comment: The problem seems to come from the alpha channel in the PNG (presumably) plus the generated PDF version. Current pdflatex generate PDF 1.5, if you set `\pdfminorversion 7` it seems to work, at least in my test with AR 9.5 on linux. Found here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/395348

Comment: That didn't work. It looks good in acroreader but when printed out onto paper, the bounding box of the image is obvious.

Comment: It does not when I print from AR 9.5 on Linux.

Comment: That's just a world of confusing. Might be a windows thing. I'll try it on a Mac later & see what happens.

Comment: On a Mac, the bounding box is present but it's not so obvious.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Comment: Which engine (pdfTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX) from what distribution are you using?

Comment: There's a chance transparency issues that occur while printing can be caused by PostScript printer drivers (which do not support transparency in bitmaps as I understood). If this is the case your document might print well with another printer or even only different driver, on the other hand you would never be able to assure that the document looks as supposed if printed by other people.

Presumably you can convert the PDF to PS using rasterization manually which should replace the "transparency" by whatever the background colour is.

Comment: Sadly this is for a document to be distributed and printed out at the recipient's discretion (and for the most part, that will be Reader via Windows) so I'll have to remove the tikzpicture in order not to have a glaring error on the page. I tried matching the colour - but it's not that easy. PNG gamma might be a problem as well

Comment: As a workaround you could probably use Inkscape to vectorize the PNG. It's not a real solution to the technical problem with the printing of transparent PNGs, but on the other hand, I believe a logo shouldn't be handed out in the form of a PNG in the first place.

Comment: What version of AR do you use? I have 9.4.1 on Linux and transparent PNG always have problems.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168333/1871